# Can we get a wildcard asterisk for selecting multiple tags to include & ignore?

Tags: support, feature-request, tags

Can we get a wildcard asterisk for selecting multiple tags to include & ignore?

If I want to include "search-engine" & "search-engines", can I use "search-engine*" to highlight both in the main question list? Or "google*" to highlight anything related to Google's search engine? It would simply be convenient, instead of having to include 4-6 related tags.

Also wanting to hide anything like "*seo*" would gray out everything that's SEO related from the main question list.

Comment: If we have very similar tags like [Tag:search-engine] and [Tag:search-engines], they should probably be merged.  In fact, it appears that they already are tag synonyms.

Comment: I wanted to use `*search*` to target these: `search`, `google-search`, `search-engines`, `search-results`, `google-image-search` & `site-search`. I found out that by simply entering `*search*` into the tags list & pressing add (rather than selecting a tag), would flag all similar searches using wildcards. I think I've discovered more of an Easter Egg (using wildcards), than the intended UI action (clicking on a tag, to add it to the filter list).

Answer (score 5):

Oh wait. I've just discovered that it already does that. Nevermind!

Comment: Best answer I have ever seen here!!